# Type guard error after updating typescript from 2.0.3 to 2.1.4

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0, typescript2.1

```
class A {
   type: string
}

interface AClass<T extends A> {
    prototype: T
}

function isType<T extends A>(a: A, aClass: AClass<T>): a is T {
    return a.type === aClass.prototype.type
}

class B extends A {
    foo: string
}

class C extends A {}

function check(a: A) {
    if (isType(a, B)) {
        return
    }
    a.type // ok

    if (isType(a, C)) {
        return
    }
    a.type // Property 'type' does not exist on type 'never'.
}
```

The error appears when the derived class does not have any distinctive attribute. This happened after I updated TS to 2.1.4. My questions are:

- Why is there an error here? My guess is that TS bypasses the custom type check and treat `A` and `C` as they have a same type, so the next statement will not be reached, `a` will have type `never`.
- Is there any better solution than adding a dummy attribute to the derived class?

Answer (score 1):

You are right, because `A` and `C` are considered the same types by the compiler as they have the same exact structure ([Type Compatibility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html)).

You shouldn't be adding dummy attributes, if `C` has no additional members/methods then there's no point for it anyway and you can just do with having `A` and `B`.

---

#### Edit

You can do that like so:

```
class A {
    type: "B" | "C";
}

class B extends A {
    type: "B";
    foo: string
}

class C extends A {
    type: "C";
}
```

The compiler won't complain now, **BUT** you can gain the exact same thing like so:

```
class A {
    type: string;

    constructor(type: string = "A") {
        this.type = type;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    foo: string;

    constructor(foo: string) {
        super("B");
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}

let a = new A();
let b = new B("foo");
let c = new A("C");
```

The `type` property is different between `a` and `c` even though they are instances of the same class.

Comment: One use case for this is to declare some action creators in redux, where each type of actions is differentiated by the value of `type` attribute. That's why I have the function `isType`

Comment: Check my revised answer

Comment: It will get ugly as the number of derived classes gets bigger. In my case, there's about a hundred actions.

Comment: If you use TS 2.0 to compile, there's no problem. I don't know if i miss it but I don't see any breaking change or change log relating to the issue. And the code looks fine to me. In runtime, the last line can actually be reached, but the control flow analysis says otherwise (`a` has type `never`). It's probably a bug or something.

Comment: The 2nd option in my edit won't get ugly as the number of actions get bigger, also it doesn't result in an error compilation. The error compilation that you receive isn't a bug.